# EasyPHP not starting/stopping correctly

Tags: easyphp

so my EasyPHP devserver seems to do weird stuff. After fresh install everything runs fine, but when I stop the database & webserver, exit the EasyPHP app and then rerun it, the MySQL database becomes corrupted (I get the "#1524 - Plugin '*B0F4C1F148E1C6C781746AB4BAA1E26C88C472BB' is not loaded" - the hash seems to change) and I need to reinstall EasyPHP.
Does anyone have idea about what could cause it? I've been looking around with no success.

Running on Win 10 64bit
EasyPHP DEVSERVER 16.1.1
Seems like it's using x86 Apache, PHP & MySQL.

Comment: @RyanVincent Added the info, and no, I didn't try the portable version.